# When will I be able to buy this domain? (pendingDelete, serverHold & redemptionPeriod)

Tags: domains, purchase, expiry

A domain that I want has all of these 3 "Domain Status" set.

```
Domain Status: pendingDelete https://icann.org/epp#pendingDelete
Domain Status: serverHold https://icann.org/epp#serverHold
Domain Status: redemptionPeriod https://icann.org/epp#redemptionPeriod
```

The domain expires in 2 days based on the `Registry Expiry Date`

When will I be able to acquire this domain?

Will I be able to purchase it in 2 days?